# Fetch CKAsset List Swift

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit, ckasset

I am using the code below to fetch a CKAsset List but it keeps crashing and telling me: `"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"` However the asset list is not empty in the CloudKit dashboard.

Do you know where I am going wrong?

```
var imageAssets = record.value(forKey: "membersPhotos") as! [CKAsset]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are forced unwrapping of the `record.value(forKey: "membersPhotos")` it is bad practice.

To avoid this use `if let` or `guard` conditions to always know with witch type you are working on.

Example :

```
if let imageAssets = record.value(forKey: "membersPhotos") as? [CKAsset] {

}
```

Comment: even though it is bad practice, I have the same issue and using if let doesn't solve it